# How to rearrange pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, functional-programming

How can I go from this Pandas dataframe:

```
     0    1
0  A11  A12
1  A21  A22
2  A31  A32
```

to this:

```
    0   1    2
0  r1  c1  A11
1  r1  c2  A12
2  r2  c1  A21
3  r2  c2  A22
4  r3  c1  A31
5  r3  c2  A32
```

rX is the row number (+1) of the element from the previous dataframe

cX is the column number (+1) of the element from the previous dataframe

This is the code that I was trying to write but failed:

```
# Number of samples and features
n_samples = len(df)
n_features = len(df.columns)

data = pd.DataFrame([[s for s in range(1, n_samples+1)],
                    [m for m in range(1, n_features+1)],
                    [something in here]])
```

I'm really struggling with list comprehension/functional programming. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want `r1` to be `r1` or `1`...?

Comment: @Tai Either is fine but I used r1 and c1 in the example to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pd.DataFrame.rename` and `pd.DataFrame.stack`
I also took the liberty of using Python 3.6 f-strings
Otherwise, use `str.format`

```
df.rename(
    index=lambda x: f'r{int(x)+1}',
    columns=lambda x: f'c{int(x)+1}'
).stack().reset_index().set_axis([0, 1, 2], axis=1, inplace=False)

    0   1    2
0  r1  c1  A11
1  r1  c2  A12
2  r2  c1  A21
3  r2  c2  A22
4  r3  c1  A31
5  r3  c2  A32
```

---

Or a pure comprehension version

```
pd.DataFrame([
    (f'r{i+1}', f'c{j+1}', v)
    for i, r in enumerate(df.values)
    for j, v in enumerate(r)
])

    0   1    2
0  r1  c1  A11
1  r1  c2  A12
2  r2  c1  A21
3  r2  c2  A22
4  r3  c1  A31
5  r3  c2  A32
```

---

Or similarly

```
v = df.values
n, m = v.shape

pd.DataFrame([
    (f'r{i+1}', f'c{j+1}', v[i, j])
    for i in range(n) for j in range(m)
])

    0   1    2
0  r1  c1  A11
1  r1  c2  A12
2  r2  c1  A21
3  r2  c2  A22
4  r3  c1  A31
5  r3  c2  A32
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you remember, but you answered another question of mine 24 hours ago. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I do remember!  Glad I could help (-:

Answer (score 0):

Try `stack` + `reset_index`

```
df_new = df.stack().reset_index()
df_new[["level_0", "level_1"]] = df_new[["level_0", "level_1"]].astype(int) + 1
df_new

    level_0 level_1 0
0   1       1       A11
1   1       2       A12
2   2       1       A21
3   2       2       A22
4   3       1       A31
5   3       2       A32
```

`df.stack()` gives a multi-index series

```
0  0    A11
   1    A12
1  0    A21
   1    A22
2  0    A31
   1    A32
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first rename column and index, then stack columns and reset_index.

```
(
    df.rename(columns=lambda x: 'c{}'.format(int(x)+1))
    .rename(index=lambda x: 'r{}'.format(int(x)+1))
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .set_axis([0,1,2], axis=1, inplace=False)
)
Out[39]: 
    0   1    2
0  r1  c1  A11
1  r1  c2  A12
2  r2  c1  A21
3  r2  c2  A22
4  r3  c1  A31
5  r3  c2  A32
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using melt ?

```
df.index=['r1','r2','r3']
df.columns=['c1','c2']

df.reset_index().melt('index')
Out[70]: 
  index variable value
0    r1       c1   A11
1    r2       c1   A21
2    r3       c1   A31
3    r1       c2   A12
4    r2       c2   A22
5    r3       c2   A32
```